# Using a DCGAN to create an intrusion detection system

Tags: pytorch, gan

- The TL;DR of my question is how do you write a discriminator and generator of a DCGAN in pytorch to accept a csv file instead of an image?

I am attempting to partial recreate an experiment from the following research paper: 
A Simple Recurrent Unit Model Based Intrusion Detection System With DCGAN
by Jin Yang et al.

Specifically I am currently trying to get a DCGAN to work by taking in a data set consisting of malicious user activity from a network firewall from the CSE-CIC-IDS2018 dataset, and I would like to receive an output from the generator that contains new unique packets of data that would appear to be malicious so that I can use those packets to increase the number of malicious packets I have available to train a neural network to detect malicious activity on a network.

This data set comes in a csv file that has one packet per row and there are 78 columns with various information about the packets themselves.

I haven't been able to find example code where this has been accomplished on something other than pictures. So I have used some code that I found for images and have been attempting to modify that code.

I began and then modified the code provided on the following website: [dcgan_faces_tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#inputs)

I wrote my own dataset class for the DCGAN using information from the following website: 
[data_loading_tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/data_loading_tutorial.html)

My code so far is as follows:

```
# Set random seed for reproducibility
manualSeed = 999
#manualSeed = random.randint(1, 10000) # use if you want new results
print("Random Seed: ", manualSeed)
random.seed(manualSeed)
torch.manual_seed(manualSeed)

# Root for the IPS dataset.
ipsroot = 'test.csv'

# Number of workers for dataloader
workers = 0

# Batch size during training
batch_size = 128

# Spatial size of training images. All images will be resized to this
#   size using a transformer.
image_size = 64

# Number of channels in the training images. For color images this is 3
nc = 3

# Size of z latent vector (i.e. size of generator input)
nz = 100

# Size of feature maps in generator
ngf = 64

# Size of feature maps in discriminator
ndf = 64

# Number of training epochs
num_epochs = 1

# Learning rate for optimizers
lr = 0.0002

# Beta1 hyperparam for Adam optimizers
beta1 = 0.5

# Number of GPUs available. Use 0 for CPU mode.
ngpu = 1

class PacketDataset(Dataset):
        """IPS 2018 Dataset."""

        def __init__(self, csv_file, transform=None):

            """
            Args:
                csv_file (string): Path to the csv file with annotations.
                #root_dir (string): Directory with all the images.
                transform (callable, optional): Optional transform to be applied on a sample.
            """

            self.packets_data = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
            self.transform = transform
        def __len__(self):
            return len(self.packets_data)

        def __getitem__(self, idx):
            if torch.is_tensor(idx):
                idx = idx.tolist()


            packets = self.packets_data.iloc[idx, 0:]#.as_list()
            packets = np.array([packets])
            packets = packets.astype('float')


            #sample = {'All Data': packets, 'Answer': packets[79]}

            #if self.transform:
                #packets = self.transform(packets)

            return packets


packet_dataset = PacketDataset(csv_file=ipsroot)

# Create the dataloader
dataloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(packet_dataset, batch_size=batch_size,
                                         shuffle=True, num_workers=workers)

# Decide which device we want to run on
device = torch.device("cuda:0" if (torch.cuda.is_available() and ngpu > 0) else "cpu")

# custom weights initialization called on netG and netD
def weights_init(m):
    classname = m.__class__.__name__
    if classname.find('Conv') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 0.0, 0.02)
    elif classname.find('BatchNorm') != -1:
        nn.init.normal_(m.weight.data, 1.0, 0.02)
        nn.init.constant_(m.bias.data, 0)

# Generator Code

class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is Z, going into a convolution
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( nz, ngf * 8, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 8),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(ngf * 8, ngf * 4, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 4),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*4) x 8 x 8
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 4, ngf * 2, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf * 2),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf*2) x 16 x 16
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf * 2, ngf, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ngf),
            nn.ReLU(True),
            # state size. (ngf) x 32 x 32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d( ngf, nc, 4, 2, 1, bias=False),
            nn.Tanh()
            # state size. (nc) x 64 x 64
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Create the generator
netG = Generator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netG = nn.DataParallel(netG, list(range(ngpu)))

# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netG.apply(weights_init)

# Print the model
print(netG)

class Discriminator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, ngpu):
        super(Discriminator, self).__init__()
        self.ngpu = ngpu
        self.main = nn.Sequential(
            # input is (nc) x 64 x 64
            nn.Conv1d(ndf, nc, 1, bias=False),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),
            # state size. (ndf) x 32 x 32
            nn.Conv1d(nc, ndf, 1, bias=False),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(ndf * 2),
            nn.LeakyReLU(0.2, inplace=True),

            # state size. (ndf*8) x 4 x 4
            nn.Conv2d(ndf * 8, 1, 4, 1, 0, bias=False),
            nn.Sigmoid()
        )

    def forward(self, input):
        return self.main(input)

# Create the Discriminator
netD = Discriminator(ngpu).to(device)

# Handle multi-gpu if desired
if (device.type == 'cuda') and (ngpu > 1):
    netD = nn.DataParallel(netD, list(range(ngpu)))

# Apply the weights_init function to randomly initialize all weights
#  to mean=0, stdev=0.2.
netD.apply(weights_init)

# Print the model
print(netD)

# Initialize BCELoss function
criterion = nn.BCELoss()

# Create batch of latent vectors that we will use to visualize
#  the progression of the generator
fixed_noise = torch.randn(64, nz, 1, 1, device=device)

# Establish convention for real and fake labels during training
real_label = 1
fake_label = 0

# Setup Adam optimizers for both G and D
optimizerD = optim.Adam(netD.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))
optimizerG = optim.Adam(netG.parameters(), lr=lr, betas=(beta1, 0.999))

# Training Loop

# Lists to keep track of progress
img_list = []
G_losses = []
D_losses = []
iters = 0

netD = netD.double()


print("Starting Training Loop...")
# For each epoch
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    # For each batch in the dataloader
    for i, data in enumerate(dataloader, 0):

        ############################
        # (1) Update D network: maximize log(D(x)) + log(1 - D(G(z)))
        ###########################
        ## Train with all-real batch
        netD.zero_grad()
        # Format batch
        real_cpu = data.to(device)
        b_size = real_cpu.size(0)
        label = torch.full((b_size,), real_label, device=device)
        # Forward pass real batch through D
        output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1).double()
        # Calculate loss on all-real batch
        errD_real = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate gradients for D in backward pass
        errD_real.backward()
        D_x = output.mean().item()



        ## Train with all-fake batch
        # Generate batch of latent vectors
        noise = torch.randn(b_size, nz, 1, 1, device=device)
        # Generate fake image batch with G
        fake = netG(noise)
        label.fill_(fake_label)
        # Classify all fake batch with D
        output = netD(fake.detach()).view(-1)
        # Calculate D's loss on the all-fake batch
        errD_fake = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate the gradients for this batch
        errD_fake.backward()
        D_G_z1 = output.mean().item()
        # Add the gradients from the all-real and all-fake batches
        errD = errD_real + errD_fake
        # Update D
        optimizerD.step()


        ############################
        # (2) Update G network: maximize log(D(G(z)))
        ###########################
        netG.zero_grad()
        label.fill_(real_label)  # fake labels are real for generator cost
        # Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
        output = netD(fake).view(-1)
        # Calculate G's loss based on this output
        errG = criterion(output, label)
        # Calculate gradients for G
        errG.backward()
        D_G_z2 = output.mean().item()
        # Update G
        optimizerG.step()

        # Output training stats
        if i % 50 == 0:
            print('[%d/%d][%d/%d]\tLoss_D: %.4f\tLoss_G: %.4f\tD(x): %.4f\tD(G(z)): %.4f / %.4f'
                  % (epoch, num_epochs, i, len(dataloader),
                     errD.item(), errG.item(), D_x, D_G_z1, D_G_z2))

        # Save Losses for plotting later
        G_losses.append(errG.item())
        D_losses.append(errD.item())

        # Check how the generator is doing by saving G's output on fixed_noise
        if (iters % 500 == 0) or ((epoch == num_epochs-1) and (i == len(dataloader)-1)):
            with torch.no_grad():
                fake = netG(fixed_noise).detach().cpu()
            #img_list.append(vutils.make_grid(fake, padding=2, normalize=True))

        iters += 1
```

And this is the output when I attempt to run that code:

```
runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset')
Random Seed:  999
Generator(
  (main): Sequential(
    (0): ConvTranspose2d(100, 8, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (1): BatchNorm2d(8, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (2): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (3): ConvTranspose2d(8, 4, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (4): BatchNorm2d(4, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (5): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (6): ConvTranspose2d(4, 2, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (7): BatchNorm2d(2, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (8): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (9): ConvTranspose2d(2, 1, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (10): BatchNorm2d(1, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (11): ReLU(inplace=True)
    (12): ConvTranspose2d(1, 78, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(2, 2), padding=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (13): Tanh()
  )
)
Discriminator(
  (main): Sequential(
    (0): Conv1d(1, 78, kernel_size=(1,), stride=(1,), bias=False)
    (1): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2, inplace=True)
    (2): Conv1d(78, 1, kernel_size=(1,), stride=(1,), bias=False)
    (3): BatchNorm2d(2, eps=1e-05, momentum=0.1, affine=True, track_running_stats=True)
    (4): LeakyReLU(negative_slope=0.2, inplace=True)
    (5): Conv2d(8, 1, kernel_size=(4, 4), stride=(1, 1), bias=False)
    (6): Sigmoid()
  )
)
Starting Training Loop...
Training with all-real batch.
Formatting all-real batch.
Forwarding pass real batch through D.
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-45-7cc744ec2577>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset/test.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset')

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 827, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset/test.py", line 294, in <module>
    output = netD(real_cpu).view(-1).double()

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:/Users/user/Desktop/Class/CS 898AN/2018 IPS Dataset/test.py", line 233, in forward
    return self.main(input)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\container.py", line 92, in forward
    input = module(input)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\module.py", line 541, in __call__
    result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py", line 59, in forward
    self._check_input_dim(input)

  File "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\torch\nn\modules\batchnorm.py", line 244, in _check_input_dim
    .format(input.dim()))

ValueError: expected 4D input (got 3D input)
```

I think changed the kernel size to 1, which I think gives a 1x1, do I actually need a 1x1 for this task?

I understand that I have given it the wrong dimensions, but I'm not quite sure how to change the expected dimensions of the input.

What do I need to modify to get the discriminator and the generator working on the data set that I have?